# In app purchase expiration content

Tags: ios, in-app-billing, storekit

My application currently allows the user to purchase Non-consumable products. I have a Built-in product delivery model which do not involve a developer server.

Im thinking of adding more content which will expire after 1 year. Upon expiration user should have the option to buy the content again. I would prefer the content not being auto renewed. My questions are as follows.

- Does the app store only allow magazines and news paper items to be
  auto-renewable? The content Im focusing might not have an update
  after renewing. Can I renew with the same content after 1 year?
- Do I need a server to implement auto-renewable? Can I use the current
  Built-in product delivery model to validate the receipts?
- What would be the main disadvantage of Non-renewing subscriptions ?
  Does it mean that the app store never provides transaction
  information  paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished call
  back?

Any help on this matter would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It depends on whether you're planning to have your newspaper or magazine in the App Store, or in Newsstand. If you're wanting it to appear in Newsstand, it'll need to have an auto-renewable subscription. If you just want it listed in the regular App Store, you can use whatever IAPs you wish.

2) You don't need a server (despite what the documentation seems to imply), you can verify the receipts from within the app (I've done this in several Newsstand apps). You'll have the receipt as an NSData object, you then need to encode it as a Base64 string and embed it in an HTTP request to Apple's verification servers. You can find a method for doing the conversion from NSData to Base64 string here: [How to encode NSData as base64? (iPhone/iPad)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584396/how-to-encode-nsdata-as-base64-iphone-ipad)

3) Yes, the disadvantage with non-renewing subscriptions is that you have to do all the work in terms of restoring, cancelling, and making the subscription expire (you can't set a time limit in iTunes Connect for them). Check the In App Purchase guide for more details on what your app is responsible for with non-renewing subscriptions (scroll down to the Registering Products with the App Store section): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html

Comment: @petermorris Thank you very much for answering all of my questions :) . I guess I will go forward with auto-renewable subscriptions.

Comment: @petermorris I discovered that using auto-renewable subscription for anything else other than newspapers or magazine would result in rejection. Check this on the review guidelines. "Apps may only use auto renewing subscriptions for periodicals (newspapers, magazines), business Apps (enterprise, productivity, professional creative, cloud storage) and media Apps (video, audio, voice), or the App will be rejected."

Comment: @Jani Yes, it really depends on what you're selling. They cover media and business-type SAAS apps as well as magazines, but it would be off limits to games or anything else. I think I read your question wrong; I thought you wanted to add a magazine app to the usual App Store instead of Newsstand.