# base64 encoding conversion issue

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, base64

Here my code for conversion a image,

```
CGSize newSize1=CGSizeMake(720.00, 576);
self.imageData = [PDFImageConverter convertImageToPDF:image1 withResolution:300 maxBoundsRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 194, 154) pageSize:newSize1];
largerbtn.selected=YES;
smallerbtn.selected=NO;
CGSize newSize=CGSizeMake(194, 154);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
//NSData *imageData1
imageData1=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 1.0);
//NSString *encodedString
encodedString= [Base64 encode:imageData1];//crashed when it reached here
NSLog(@"%@",encodedString);
```

The application getting crashed when it reaches the base64 conversion,What wrong with my code.Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: check `imageData1` is nil,when trying to encode

Comment: @LithuT.V i did ,its not nil .Its shows `NSShadow {0, 0} color = {UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.5 0.5 0.5 1}`

Comment: which class you are using to encode?

Comment: Can you provide some code explaining image1 object. from where u get image1.??

Comment: @LithuT.V im using Base64.h class to encode

Comment: @SatishAzad `//IBOutlet UIImageView *imgframe; UIImage *image1;                   imgframe.image=image1;`

Comment: Try using UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);  instead of UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 1.0);

Comment: HI Please refer this link :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584396/how-to-encode-nsdata-as-base64-iphone-ipad

Comment: @SatishAzad But i want the image in JPG format

Comment: If u want image in JPG formate convert it from PNG to JPG. BTW u didnt explained about from where u get image either form Camera or from library or bundle or any other source??

Comment: @SatishAzad images from application itself(bundle)

Comment: it is .png image in bundle??

Comment: @SatishAzad its in JPG

Comment: Please refer below link, it may be helpful to you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584396/how-to-encode-nsdata-as-base64-iphone-ipad

Comment: what xcode version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   // Use this line 
     imageData1=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 1.0);
      NSString *encodedString = [imageData base64Encoding];
```

Comment: i did same error with log `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSShadow bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9d31780`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 [Base64 initialize];
```

before using

```
[Base64 encode:imageData1].
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No still crashed , it shows the following LOG `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSShadow bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9d31780`

Answer (score 0):

you miss initialization of Base64 class as

```
[Base64 initialize];
```

include this line, before you try to encode

Comment: So what? I didnt get you

Comment: yeah i did,im getting a error log `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSShadow bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9d31780`